# Finding files using regular expressions/wildcards

Tags: regex, bash, find, wildcard

Within a particular directory, I have a series of files that are labelled sequentially:`image0000.png`, `image0001.png`, `image0002.png`, etc.. They are labelled by number, but I don't necessarily know how many preceding zeroes there are in the filename, i.e. whether it will be `image0001.png` or `image00001.png`.

Within a bash script, I wish to find a single file at a time (over a for loop), and then apply some processing to the file. This search could start at zero and end before I've reached the end, or could be of varying steps. To expand, I could want to find `image0000.png`, `image0001.png`, `image0002.png` and so forth, or I could start at `image0010.png` and find every other file, i.e. the next two would be `image0012.png` and `image0014.png`.

To try and find the first file (`image0000.png`), I've tried using find and ls, with the following outputs:

```
$ find video/figs/ -name 'image*[0]0.png'
video/figs/image00100.png
video/figs/image00000.png
$ ls video/figs/image*[0]0.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 user machine 165K Feb 19 09:06 video/figs/image00000.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 user machine 207K Feb 19 09:06 video/figs/image00100.png
```

Similar results occur for finding the second (i.e., `find video/figs/ -name 'image*[0]0.png'` finds `image00101.png` and `image00001.png`. So it's finding the file I want (`image00001.png`), but is also finding one that I don't (`image00101.jpg`). Can anyone help me understand why, and fix it?

Comment: Thank you - is there a way to limit the expression of *? I'd been hoping that `*[0]` would indicate that I was looking for zero or more matches of `0`, but perhaps that is more regex-y than wilccards will allow. Notably, `find video/skin/figs/ -regex 'image*[0]1.png'` finds no matches at all.

Comment: What is the criterion, to not find i00101.png? It's a number (101), preceded with zeros (00). Why is i00000.png allowed? i00011.png is fine too? Zeros only tolerated on the left?

Comment: Apologies for not making it clearer - I am trying to find file 1, then file 2, then file 3, etc. (potentially file 1, then file 3, and so on). I thus only wish to have zeroes to the left of the number file that I'm looking for, as you surmised.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Won't work. Try `touch image00{8..12}.png; touch image000{8..12}.png`. Apart from not sorting by number before the dot, it includes image0010.png, which is, but unknown reasons, taboo. :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: But im0101.png is not. Why?

Comment: @PhilG: Point out, why you use find. Do you want to search over subdirectories? Do you want to sort ignoring the subdirectories? im008, im009 are fine, im010 is bad im011 is fine again?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: The **im** is my abbrevation - I guess we're talking about numbers and leading zeros, and zeros in the middle.

Comment: Do you need to loop over them in order?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `ls` and `grep` for that:

```
ls | grep -oP 0*[1-9]+.png
```

Example:

```
$:/tmp/test$ ls
00001.png 00002.png 00010.png 00013.png 00201.png

$:/tmp/test$ ls | grep -oP 0*[1-9]+.png
00001.png
00002.png
00013.png
01.png
```

Comment: You are missing a 0 digit in the regular expression, e.g. it won't work for "0010.png". I just edited your answer to match numbers ended in '0'.

Comment: @vbarboza I thought OP wants to exclude those.

Comment: Then you're corect, sorry!

Comment: That doesn't match image0000.png.

Comment: @userunknown I'm not sure OP wants to have it. The question is a bit vague to me now, I'm waiting for OP's input on my answer.

Comment: @Maroun: Yes, the attempt to describe, what the criterion is, seems changing and unclear. But now the last sentence says `The file I'll be looking for will be identified by the number, hence wanting to find image0000.png, then image0001.png`.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion - I'll redraft the post to try and make it clearer

Comment: If you would parse the output of `ls`, you should probably mention the problems with it, and what the better alternatives are (e.g. such as globbing to a Bash array).

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/44425), [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you don't want to dive into subdirectories, and find files, sorted by number, spread over subdirs.

So find isn't necessary.

```
ls image*{08..10}.png
image00010.png  image0008.png  image0009.png  image0010.png  image008.png  image009.png
```

Part 2 of your question, only find every other file:

```
ls image*{08..10..2}.png
image00010.png  image0008.png  image0010.png  image008.png
```

Maybe you know for-loops. It's like that,

```
for (i in 8 to 10 by 2)
```

or

```
for (int i=8; i <= 10; i+=2)
```

Restricting the search to find image image00010.png but not imageAB010.png wouldn't work.

The reason to exclude 101 is still unclear. Maybe it's only a sorting thing.

With directories, which aren't the PWD, there is no big difference:

```
ls video/figs/image*{08..10..2}.png
```

Note, that instead of ls, you use just the program, you want to process on the files, if the program is able to handle more than one file at a time, like ls.

Answer (score 0):

Sincere thanks to everyone who contributed an answer - perhaps I explained it poorly, or I was too wedded to the code I'd already written to use any of the provided answers. However, I've found the following solutions:

**1) Why did I find more answers than I expected?**

`find video/figs/ -name 'image*[0]0.png'` uses very limited comprehension of wildcards, and thus the above was interpreted as finding a file with name `image<wildcard>00.png`. There is no way, using the `-name` option, to restrict the application of `*` to match only a given character (in this case, only find zero or more matches to `0`.

**2) How do I find the image files with an unknown number of padding zeroes?**

The following is a MWE from my final code. It demonstrates how to search within a given directory `SEARCH_DIR` (not necessarily including subdirectories, but I haven't checked)

```
f1=0 # Starting number
f2=10 # End number
df=2 # number to skip between images
for ((f=$f1; f<=$f2; f=$f+$df)); do
   export iFile=$(find $SEARCH_DIR -regex '.*/image0*'$f'.png')
done
```

The `export` ensures the variable is available to sub-processes, with the `iFile=$()` syntax allowing me to export the result of the command to the variable `iFile`. The bit within the parentheses is the bit I was looking for: `find $SEARCH_DIR -regex '.*/image[0]*'$f'.png'`

a) `find $SEARCH_DIR` specifies the location for the search

b) `-regex` specifies to use regular expressions, which are more powerful than standard bash scripting and allow me to limit wildcards as required

c) `'.*/image0*'$f'.png'`: The regular expression search looks over the entire string, so apparently I need the initial `.*/` to perform the match. The `0*` now performs as I originally wanted - the `*` wildcard is now searching for zero or more matches of the preceding term, which here is `0` (so if I wanted to search for zero or more matches of any digit, I would use `[0-9]*`). The `$f` term is to search for the numbered file in the for loop.